# Getting path of a file in a wcf service assembly

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-assembly, filepath

I've an assembly that is referenced by a WCF service hosted in IIS. The assembly uses some XSLT files and I'm confused where to dump these files either creating a folder in assembly project itself or in the WCF service side and how I can get the physical path of the xslt file in the assembly?

Comment: any final solution about it ? I have similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691426/get-svchost-assembly-location-path-using-svcimplementation-assembly

Answer (score 3):

Since IIS-hosted WCF services only tend to copy the DLL to the temp folder and not the content of the project that is set to copy to output, one need to reference the actual codebase of the dll.

```
var codeBase = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase;
                    codeBase = codeBase.Substring(8); //Remove the "file:///" prefix in front of the actual path.

var dir = codeBase.Substring(0, codeBase.LastIndexOf("/", System.StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1); //Cut out the dll file name.

var file = @"ErrorMessages.xml";

var targetPath = dir + file;
```

Comment: I have  Service.Host.dll and SvcImpl.dll (<%@ ServiceHost Service="SvcImpl"  %>)
Service  Host in IIS.
This code in SvcImpl.dll:
1) Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() gets null.
2) Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() gets SvcImpl.
3) Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(); gets System.ServiceModel.

How can I get Service.Host assembly programatically in SvcImpl if Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() gets null?. View details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691426/get-svchost-assembly-location-path-using-svcimplementation-assembly

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a sub-folder of the referenced assembly, mark them as **Content** and enable *Copy to Output Directory*.
Then, in the assembly code where you need the path to the file, get the path of the executing assembly and add expected sub-folder to the path, for example:

```
var dllPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(  
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var targetPath = Path.Combine(dllPath, "XsltFolder");
```

Comment: I've done as you said but I'm getting the following error Could not find a part of the path 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\d5e86da5\28c7474e\assembly\dl3\e3edeed7\4bb2927d_561fcc01\AV.BackOffice.Caliber.DLL\XSLTs\Violations.xslt'. The GetExecutingAssembly().Loaction is not returning the expected path I think but the XSLTs folder is copied to the debug directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath

Answer (score 0):

Any XSLT, or XML files should be placed relative to root folder of WCF Service folder, root folder can be achieved as below:

if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                // "~/"  gives root physical folder of the virtual directory of the WCF Service this Biz dll supporting..., 
                // for ex: E:\PhyPath\WCFServiceFolder\
                RequestPhysicalPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");
            }